# Can't login to Umbraco "Login failed for user"

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I attmpted to login to my Umbraco build today and received the following error: "Login failed for user"
The console displays:
The requesteds resource does not support http methot 'GET'
It pings back the "login failed" so quick that I'm doubtful it is even hitting the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login was failing due to redirects forcing a trailing "/"